# Differential of $f$ at $0$ in a new basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $f: R^m \to R^n$ be a map determined by differentiable functions (not necessarily linear), such that
> $$ f(x_1,...,x_m) = (...,f_i(x_1,...,x_m),...), i = 1,...n $$ and $$ f_i(0,...,0) = 0, i = 1,...n $$
> Determine the linear map, named differential of $f$ at $0$ as
> $$ (df_0)(e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{df_i}{dx_j}(0)e'_i = (\frac{df_1}{dx_j}(0), ..., \frac{df_n}{dx_j}(0))$$
> Where $\{e_i\}$ and $\{e'_i\}$ are the standard basis of $R^m, R^n$. Show that if we change the basises and compute $df_0$ by the same formula in the new basises then the new linear map $df_0$ will correspond with the old one.

My thoughts:
Let the new basis of $R^m$ be $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ and $v_j = \sum_{j=1}^m a_je_j$. Let the new basis of $R^n$ be $\{w_1,..., w_n\}$ and $w_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b_ie'_i$ then using the linearity of $df_0$,

$$ (df_0)(v_j) = (df_0)(\sum_{j=1}^{m} a_je_j) = (\sum_{j=1}^{m} a_j*(df_0)(e_j) =  \sum_{j=1}^{m}a_j\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{df_i}{dx_j}(0)e'_i =  = \sum_{j=1}^{m}a_j(\frac{df_1}{dx_j}(0), ..., \frac{df_n}{dx_j}(0))$$

What to do next? I don't understand if $\frac{df_1}{dx_j}(0) = \frac{df_i(0,...,0)}{x_j} = 0$ or not.